# GMSPlaceField Error when building - Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, xcode, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have an app that's using [Google's Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete), so I've been following the example code that's been provided.
I've added the GooglePlace pod to my podfile and since I'm using the same 
full-screen control, I'm using their sample code.

No error shows until I try to build the project and when I do build, Im getting this error: "Use of undeclared type 'GMSPlaceField'" on line 29

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update you podfile.. error will be remove

Comment: Wow I had no idea it was this simple. I tried everything but that lol. Thanks man

Comment: Not working .. 

i have same issue 

"Use of undeclared identifier 'GMSPlaceField' "

Comment: @vipulkumarmehta did you try after update the podfile ?