# Use of Undeclared Type GMSPlacesField GoogleMaps SDK Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, google-places-autocomplete

Using the GooglePlaces Autocomplete UI I'm getting a error Use of undeclared type 'GMSPlacefield'.

I've search here
[GMSPlaceField Error when building - Swift 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586008/gmsplacefield-error-when-building-swift-4-2)

I've tried updating the pod file I'm using google places 3.1.0 and google maps 3.1.0. I've restarted clean build.

I think the code is good code because it's used in multiple places on the google documentation. 
https://woolpert-googlecloud.github.io/maps-platform-best-practices/docs/place-details-fields.html

The specific line of code that is failing is 
      let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue:
        UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) | UInt(GMSPlaceField.placeID.rawValue))!

The compiler indicates the use of undeclared type 'GMSPlaceField'

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to update the Pod file.  I got the report out
Performing CocoaPods Installation
Installing GoogleMaps (3.1.0)
Installing GooglePlaces (3.1.0)
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.

But this wasn't true upon revivification it indicated I was still at 2.7.0.

I updated the pod file to specifically call out the most recent pod file 
pod 'GooglePlaces', '~> 3.1'
pod ‘GoogleMaps’, '~> 3.1'

and this worked and resolved the issue.