# GMSPlaceField Error when building - Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I Have add Pod Google Place for Autocomplete and I've already update pod but getting error in it as below ::

```
let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) |  UInt(GMSPlaceField.addressComponents.rawValue) |  UInt(GMSPlaceField.formattedAddress.rawValue) |  UInt(GMSPlaceField.coordinate.rawValue))!
autocompleteController.placeFields = fields
```

> Error : Use of undeclared type 'GMSPlaceField'.

Comment: Have your imported `GooglePlaces` in your Swift file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GMSPlaceField Error when building - Swift 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586008/gmsplacefield-error-when-building-swift-4-2)

Comment: Yes I have Imported GooglePlaces